# Pycharm - How to open command prompt or launch separate, independent script?

Tags: subprocess, pycharm, command-prompt

I've got a python script that runs for several hours at a time (Script A). For certain events, I'd like the script to launch/run a new script (Script B) that runs independently of the first so that if I need to stop Script A, I can do so without killing Script B.

Is this possible? I've tried using `subprocess`, but can't seem to get it to launch a command prompt in the foreground--it launches in the background and I can't tell if it's working or not.

Edit:

I can get it running using:

`os.system("start cmd.exe /c python {} {} {}".format(directory, varA, varB))` but for some reason, it opens like 10 command prompt windows instead of just 1. Same thing happens if I use `subprocess` instead of `os.system` Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Well, found my own solution. `os.system` worked if I used `start` as the first argument. And the way to stop it from being called multiple times was to use `if __name__ == "__main__":`. I didn't have that previously and when calling the function directly and then using `Run` in PyCharm, it called it too many times.